# Cannot add external JavaScript file to React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have read all advices how to add external JavaScript file to React application but no one works for me. I'll describe my situation.  I have created a tutorial React project and it works fine. Now I want to show a data that I get from server side in some grid , say, jqgrid. I have a JavaScript file that has a function showGrid() to show the grid. So I need to add this file to the project. More precisely I have a React component **ShowInGrid** and in

```
render()
```

method of it I write

```
let contents = this.state.loading
  ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    : ShowInGrid.renderGrid(this.state.data);
```

and then

```
static rendersGrid(data) {
    return (
        showGrid(data)
        
        
);
```

where **showGrid** is a function from JavaScript file. To reference to this file I used several ways:

1. in **componentDidMount** method I added

   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = // path of external javascript file.
   script.class = "external-script
   document.body.appendChild(script);

I get a message

> 'showGrid' is not defined  no-undef

2. I tried to use

   import ScriptTag from 'react-script-tag';
   with

   <  ScriptTag isHydrating={true} type="text/javascript" src="http://my path to js-file">

but I get the same result.
So I really need to know what's wrong and how properly to add JavaScript file to app. A real working example will be really appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to call `ShowInfoGrid` from within the render method of `ShowInfoGrid`?

Comment: If you have `showGrid` in some JavaScript file, you can export it from there using `export default showGrid` and then import in your React component: `import showGrid from 'path-to-that-js-file'`

Comment: To Andy: I call showGrid, not ShowInfoGrid .

Comment: To tromgy: I tried to add export default showGrid to my JavaScript file but I get a message: Unexpected token 'export'. Beside that how can I add something to external files that are not mine?

Comment: Your environment probably doesn't support ES6 syntax. export and import are ES6 syntaxes